# Summing a column based on other columns values

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to sum values of one column based on another column(s) value as efficiently as possible.  I was not sure if there was a way to use the summarize command.  Here is an example data set:

```
Cancer1   Cancer2   Cancer3   Disease1
1         0         1         1
0         1         0         0
1         0         0         1
```

In this case I am looking to sum Disease1 based on if the person has a given cancer. I am looking for an output that would say the total number of people that have Cancer1 and Disease1 is 2, the total number of people that have Cancer2 and Disease1 is 0 and the total number of people that have Cancer3 and Disease1 is 1.

Answer (score 1):

We can create the variable using `rowSums` on the 'Cancer' columns and then multiply with the binary 'Disease' column

```
df1$newCol <- (rowSums(df1[1:3] > 0)) * df1$Disease1
df1$newCol
#[1] 2 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at `dplyr::count()`.

```
# sum up the number of people that have Cancer1 and Disease1:
foo <- ds %>% count(Cancer1 , Disease1)

# extract the integer result you are looking for:
foo %>% filter(Cancer1 == 1, Disease1== 1) %>% pull(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going right away to a code-answer, I'd like to offer some (unsolicited) advise regarding the formatting of the data:

It seems to me that you could profit a lot from having a long table, instead of the wide one you have (You may have many more cancer types, such as "cancer_n"; and many more diseases, like "disease_n"). For having a long table, you may find it necessary to define some sort of id for each record. Also, for completeness of the results, I'd like to offer a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table) # loads the package

a <- data.table(id = 1:3, 
                Cancer1 = c(1,0,1), 
                Cancer2 = c(0,1,0), 
                Cancer3 = c(1, 0,0), 
                Disease1 = c(1,0,1)) # create a data.table with an additional id

# melt the data.table (make it long-form), and calculate the expected result:
melt(a, c("Disease1", "id"))[Disease1 == 1 & value == 1, .N, by = variable]

   variable N
1:  Cancer1 2
2:  Cancer3 1
```